# How to make an existing polygon move in java?

Tags: java, polygon, move, translate

Hey dudes and dudettes. 
High-school Comp Sci student reporting in.

Right now we're doing some work with plotting and polygons, and one of the challenges is to make it move across the screen in a variety of ways. (left to right, etc.) See, this would be no issue if I knew the language or had the means to study it at a basic level. But our teacher just hands us some environment and some code to copy and paste and look off of, none of which really helps in the long run, except for the most basic stuff.

So, my friends, I can make a polygon through plotting points as shown here:

```
int xPoints[]={  xP*684/1000,xP*706/1000, xP*661/1000, xP*687/1000,
                 xP*735/1000,xP*760/1000, xP*723/1000, xP*713/1000,
                 xP*698/1000,xP*686/1000, xP*669/1000, xP*653/1000,
                 xP*639/1000,xP*639/1000, xP*641/1000, xP*648/1000};


int yPoints[]={ yP*354/1000, yP*354/1000, yP*472/1000, yP*472/1000,
                yP*354/1000, yP*354/1000, yP*452/1000, yP*471/1000,
                yP*487/1000, yP*498/1000, yP*503/1000, yP*504/1000,
                yP*492/1000, yP*473/1000, yP*455/1000, yP*440/1000};
int numPoints=16;
```

But I cannot figure out for the life of me what kind of specific input or code is required to make it move. (by that I mean translate across the the screen)
Any hints to get me on the right track would be greatly appreciated. I don't exactly have the means of figuring this out on my own.

Edit: Whoops, yep it's Java.

Comment: Let's simplify things a little bit and just start with a single point. If you initially draw it at the point (x, y), what would you do to it to the left?

Comment: Hi, I agree, it's really hard to figure out what you need to do here. Did you get any other info with the question at all? Can you ask your teacher what programming language this is?

Comment: @TarynEast The Q is tagged as Java, so I assume that is the language. Clarification on that point would be good, though.

Comment: Are we trying to do this in a graphical environment such as Swing or AWT??

Comment: IBM VisualAge, so yeah graphical environment I suppose.

Comment: Did you have a Graphical enviroment in mind?  Swing, AWT, SWT, Slick2D ... ?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO! You need to break this down into small parts that you need to figure out how to do. Some that come to mind are

1. Create a window to draw in.
2. Draw a line in that window.
3. Draw a polygon in the window.
4. Move a point from (x, y) in a given direction.

Each of these can likely be broken down even further. Often solving a programming problem starts with this kind of thinking. As you try to do each of these, and any others that you come up with, please feel free to come back and ask more questions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know IBM VisualAge but if you have any draw method/loop, you should increase xP to move to right, decrease it to move left etc. with a for loop, for example.

Comment: I have no knowledge of Java, but I understand changing xP to make it move. What exactly is a for loop? Edit: Also, what's a draw/method loop and how can I utilize it?

Comment: A for loop allows you to repeat a snippet of code exactly as many times as you say. This is the syntax

`for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  xP++;
}`

This would make the polygon go to the right 100 positions (i.e. pixels)

Comment: that works and moves the polygon, but my real trouble is making it move in such a manner that it looks like an animation. (i.e watching it move as the program goes through it's methods)

Comment: then the problem is that the loop is called inside the draw method and you only see the final result. Try doing only xP++ within this method, then, each time draw() is called, you should see it moving to the right

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it's a java.awt.Polygon, have you looked at

`Polygon.translate(int dx, int dy);`   ???

If it is some other kind of Polygon, check to see if it has a similar method.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a for loop?

```
for(int i=0;i<xPoints.length;i++)
    xPoints[i]+=1;// shift 1 unit
for(int i=0;i<yPoints.length;i++)
    yPoints[i]+=1;// shift 1 unit
```